# How to set activeBackgroundColor in react native for createMaterialTopTabNavigator?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I want to set default active and inactive `backGroundColor` for `createMaterialTopTabNavigator`

in my app. but it did not work correctly.

I tried to put those in style or `tabBarStyle` and also in `navigationOptions` but it's not an answer

```
Hotel:{
screen: Hotel,
navigationOptions: {
  activeBackgroundColor:  '#fff',
  inactiveBackgroundColor: '#E9EEF6',

  header: null, headerMode: 'none',swipeEnabled:false,
  tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => {
    const image = focused
    ? activeHotel
    : deactiveHotel
    return (
      <Image
        style={{ width: 50, height: 50 }}
        source={image}
        />
    )}
  }
},
Travel:{
  screen: Travel,
  navigationOptions:{
    header: null, headerMode: 'none',swipeEnabled:false,
    activeBackgroundColor:  '#fff',
    inactiveBackgroundColor: '#E9EEF6',

    tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => {
      const image = focused
      ? activeTravel
      : deactiveTravel
      return (
        <Image
          style={{ width: 50, height: 50 }}
          source={image}
          />
      )}
    }
  },
},
{
  tabBarOptions: {
    showIcon : true,
    showLabel : false,
    tabStyle: {
      height :100
    },
    style: {
      backgroundColor : '#E9EEF6',
      elevation:0
    },
    indicatorStyle :{
      backgroundColor : 'transparent',
      height :20,
    }
  }
},
{
  headerMode: 'none',
  navigationOptions: {
    headerVisible: false,
  },
},
```

I put those on Style or `TabStyle` but it did not work. when I remove

```
  backgroundColor : '#E9EEF6',
```

the both tab color become blue (default color).
is there any answer or suggestion for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem by editing style and tabStyle. in tabStyle I set backgroundColor for active tab and I set backgroundColor for inactive tab in style.

```
  style: {
    elevation : 0,
    height : 100,
    backgroundColor: 'white',  //deactiveColor
    justifyContent:'center',
    flexDirection : 'column',
  },
  tabStyle: {
    paddingTop : 20,
    backgroundColor: '#1B275A',  //activeColor
    justifyContent:'space-between',
    flexDirection : 'column',
    height : 100,
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't set active & inactive background for topTab. You can only do so for BottomTab.

But, you can set inactive and activeTintColor for the topTab